# Read/Write/Delete count on Firestore security rule denial

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

If any on my Read, Write or Delete action fails due to Firestore security rule denial, will it count as an action? In other words, I am updating a Document and it fails (because Firestore security rules does not allow the write). Will it still count as 1 write operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not count as a write.  The database actually has a register a change in a document in order to be billed as a write.

If a rule has to perform document reads using `get()` or `exists()` in order to validate an operation, then those will be billed.